# widgetFile file path using settings value

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm toying a bit with making my blog system a bit more general by introducing a theme setting in the settings file (it's a required value of type `Text`). This will hold the name of the theme which will make the widget point to that direction as such

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    extra <- getExtra
    defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile $ "theme/" ++ (extraTheme extra) ++ "/home")
```

Problem with this approach though, is that ghc tells me there is a staging issue here :/

So, question is; what would be the best approach to "dynamically" set the path to a widget file, based on the settings value? Or is it possible to override/make an alternate implementation of widgetFile that does this?

I'm using the default scaffold btw.